# Cassandra Inconsistent Range Query

Tags: get, cassandra, range, where-clause

I am performing this query:

```
newerQuery = session.prepare("SELECT key, type, timestamp, userId FROM " + TableName + " WHERE timestamp >= ? AND timestamp < ? ALLOW FILTERING;");

session.execute(newerQuery.bind(start, stop));
```

BUT when running the above query with the same parameters (start & stop) i get different results each time. The amount of rows I get back differ from 1100 to 2300. Why is this? 
It is very important for us that I can read range queries consistently.

Comment: try reading with higher consistency level, might be ALL and check the behavior

Comment: I am sorry. I am not sure how to use a higher consistency. I have tried adding "USING CONSISTENCY QUORUM", but I don't know where in the query to insert it. It fails with 
"Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:131 missing EOF at 'USING' "

Comment: `newerQuery.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ALL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a higher consistency seemed to solve the problem. Now I get the same data every time. Solution provided by Undefined_variable.

I added

```
newerQuery.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ALL);
```

and it worked!